# Postfix SMTP relay to Office 365

Tags: postfix, smtp

i trying to setup  Postfix SMTP on my CentOS 7.8 i following https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/postfix-relay-office-365/
and got stuck on this error

```
May 30 21:36:28 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: ED739106FF09: from=<none@yourpbx.com>, size=501, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 30 21:36:28 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: B7D6B111EB6E: from=<karta@kpcomputer.co.uk>, size=457, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 30 21:36:28 pbx12 postfix/smtp[17378]: fatal: garbage after "]" in server description: [kpcomputer-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com]25
May 30 21:36:28 pbx12 postfix/smtp[17379]: fatal: garbage after "]" in server description: [kpcomputer-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com]25
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/master[13378]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp pid 17378 exit status 1
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/master[13378]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/master[13378]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp pid 17379 exit status 1
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/error[17380]: ED739106FF09: to=<none@yourpbx.com>, relay=none, delay=57060, delays=57059/1/0/0.14, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
May 30 21:36:29 pbx12 postfix/error[17382]: B7D6B111EB6E: to=<karta@aktelecoms.com>, relay=none, delay=1193, delays=1192/1/0/0.13, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
May 30 21:41:28 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: E5421111EB6C: from=<karta@kpcomputer.co.uk>, size=457, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 30 21:41:28 pbx12 postfix/smtp[17931]: fatal: garbage after "]" in server description: [kpcomputer-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com]25
May 30 21:41:29 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
May 30 21:41:29 pbx12 postfix/qmgr[15174]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
May 30 21:41:29 pbx12 postfix/master[13378]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp pid 17931 exit status 1
May 30 21:41:29 pbx12 postfix/master[13378]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
May 30 21:41:29 pbx12 postfix/error[17932]: E5421111EB6C: to=<karta@aktelecoms.com>, relay=none, delay=2344, delays=2343/1/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
```

can someone please help me out

Comment: Your first problem is in your host definition; the error message highlights it; `May 30 21:36:28 pbx12 postfix/smtp[17378]: fatal: garbage after "]" in server description: [kpcomputer-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com]25`.   You need a `:` after the [host], so it should read `[kpcomputer-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com]:25`

Comment: i have add the : and run

Comment: May 31 17:41:05 pbx12.aktelecoms.co.uk postfix/error[9207]: A5ECC1053810: to=<karta@aktelecoms.com>, relay=none, delay=634, delays=634/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: cony=none, delay=634, delays=634/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to kpcomputer-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.11.10]:25: Connection timed out)